# Moles with .net 3.5

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, msbuild, mstest, moles

We are trying to use Moles in our unit tests.

However, we are running into problems because our code is currently built with .net 3.5 and upgrading it to .net 4 is currently not an option.

When I try to run the test I get the following error:

"You can only run tests using the default host adapter from a test assembly that targets .NET framework 3.5".

I have found out on another post here that this is a known limitation of VS ("Execution of .NET Framework 3.5 tests is supported only in the default host adapter").

So I then changed the target framework of the test project to .NET 4.0, which sorted my issues locally, but when I try and run the build in TFS, I get:

"A test run can only be targeted to single .Net framework version. Targeting multiple Framework version in single run is unsupported."

Any ideas how I can get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure both the target and test projects are set to .NET Framework 3.5 profile, not the client profile.